# Number of licence plates that match a criterion

Tags: combinatorics

A new license plate in Alberta consists of three letters followed by four numbers. Letters are chosen from a list of $24$ acceptable letters that may be repeated. And any digits can be used and they can be repeated.

Mr. Tran wants the first letter on his license plate to be a T, which is an acceptable letter. The $4$ digits are the exact same arrangement as the last four of his cell phone number.

I don't know the last $4$ digits of Mr. Tran's cell phone number. Does this matter when I calculate the number of licence plates that match his criteria?

Comment: Welcome! Math.SE is a high quality maths Q&A answer site and tries the best to **guide you** to fill in the blanks. What are your thoughts on this question?

Comment: I am having probables understanding how I am able to find the last four of his digits cellphone number

Comment: Whether the last digits are $2358$ or $9876$ (two random numbers i came up with), the 4 digits **have to match with** this number, and there's only one case: **to be the same with the last four digits of his cell phone number**, isn't there? The digits are not exactly important.

Comment: @FrenzyLi  the digits can be repeated as it says in the question. So could it be 9999?

Comment: The problem states: **are the exact same arrangement** with **the last four of his cell phone number**. It actually has nothing to do with the digits being repeatable.

Comment: @FrenzyLi I could attend my math class today because I was sick, so I am not able to really understand

Comment: If Mr. Tran's number ends with $9999$, sure thing. What if it's not $9999$? We don't know his number.

Comment: Your question has received 4 downvotes. This means people believe that **your question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful**. You should edit the question title to remove the blanks; make your **main issue** more specific, state where your doubt is, or your question has the risk of being put on hold.

Comment: Think of it this way. You're Mr. Tran. You know the last four digits of your cell phone number. Whatever these digits are, you will only pick a licence plate number whose last 4 digits are the same with the last four digits of your cell phone number. There's only one acceptable criteria for the last 4 digits altogether.

Comment: That means wants the first letter to be T and the 4 last digits to be his phone number. And the only thing that he doesn't care about are the two left letters right ?

Comment: So there is 576 number of licence plates that could meet his criteria as 24 letters for each ?? = 24•24= 576

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: Thank you, sorry that it took me so long to understand

Comment: When using this website in the future, think more, and be more thoughtful when you ask questions. It'll be good for everyone, especially you. Have a nice adventure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Mr.Tran wants the first letter on his license plate to be a T

The plate number will become `T ? ? ? ? ? ?` where `?` is not yet known.

> A new license plate in Alberta consists of three letters followed by four numbers. Letters are chosen from a list of 24 acceptable letters that may be repeated.

For the first two question marks, they each are chosen from the $24$ alphabets and can repeat.

> The 4 digits are the exact same arrangement as the last four of his cell phone number.

For the last four question marks, `? ? ? ?` each of them have only $1$ acceptable choice: to match with the digit in Mr. Tran's cell phone number.

Each choice is independent of the other; how many acceptable plate numbers are there in total?

Comment: So is it TTT1111?

Comment: @dianat.h You don't know the cell phone number. Mr. Tran knows, so how will he make a choice?

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm sorry

Comment: Do we go 24nCr3 =2024?

Comment: Use $\LaTeX$ to type your formula. `$formula_subscript^upperscript$` It's too much conversation in here. Second letter on the plate has $24$ choices. Third letter on the plate has $24$ choices. Each final digit has to match with the telephone number's last 4 digits exactly. How many plate numbers that match the criteria are there? My last comment.